# errors while running gulp command

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-uglify

[image: installing gulp locally]

```js
var gulp = require('gulp')
 uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('default', function(){
 gulp.src('js/*.js')
 .pipe(uglify())
 .pipe(gulp.dest('minjs'));
});
```

[image: so this error occurred]

Comment: You need a return in a gulp task. See the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't post errors as images next time.

You need to return the pipeline from the function:

```
gulp.task("default", function() {
  return gulp
    .src("js/*.js")
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("minjs"));
});
```